# Can't parse using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse "Dec 6 04:13:01" with "MMM d HH:mm:ss", but it is not working! I spent a lot of time but cant figure it out.

Any ideas why it fails?

Comment: How is not working?  Works just fine for me...

Comment: what is your default `Locale`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, but it's probably english. (response to comment on Jigar's answer)

Comment: @JigarJoshi You should undelete your answer and add information that locale need to support English names of months like `Locale.US` or `Locale.UK`.

Comment: I voted to close your question as duplicate based on assumption that over 90% of problems with parsing `MMM` involves locale which doesn't support English names of months. If that wasn't the problem feel free to inform me and I will reopen your question.

Comment: Using `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm:ss");` and inputing `Dec 6 04:13:01`, outputs `Sun Dec 06 04:13:01 EST 1970` for me.  What are your expectations?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was more curious about why you though it would help then thinking it was a mistake ;)

Comment: I see the **year is missing** in that input string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably trying to parse it with `JAPANESE` locale (guessing it from your profile + your web page), specify any english locale for example: `Locale.US`

```
String dateString = "Dec 6 04:13:01";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
System.out.println(df.parse(dateString));
```

Comment: Why?  Works just fine for me with the default local which isn't US...

Comment: it works fine with `Locale.US` , so probably it is issue with default locale of OP, but your comment is more important here, let OP specify his error

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, my locale was Japanese.